# how to use modules to hide lemmas in coq?

Tags: coq

I have a theorem T, its proof, and the zillion lemmas used in proving it.

I would like to hide the lemmas, and make available only the theorem -- mainly because I don't want to have to think of good, global names for the Lemmas.

Can I place the theorem, its proof, and the lemmas in a module, restricted with a module type, and make only the theorem available?

Something like:

```
Module Type T_MY_T.
End T_MY_T.

Module T_My_theorem : T_MY_T.
  Lemma L1: ...
  Proof. Admitted.
  Lemma L2: ...
  Proof. Admitted.
  Theorem My_Great_Theorem: ...
  Proof. apply L1; apply L2. Qed.
End T_My_theorem.
```

If so, can someone please post or point me to a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

The `Module Type A` should contain Axioms for the theorems you wish to export. The `Module B : A` contains these axioms as theorems that need to be proven. It can also contain whatever lemmas and other machinery needed to prove the theorems. To access a theorem from outside the module, you can `apply B.Theorem1`, etc.